# Failover Cluster Manager - How to make a cluster vote again

Tags: windows, failovercluster

I disabled one of the failover cluster firewall rules to test something on a node and it took the node down, re-enabling the firewall rule, brought it back online. But now the current vote says 0. How do I change it to go back to 1? Without causing any issues with the cluster.

**Fail Over Cluster Image**

[image: Fail Over Cluster Image]

Output from: `Get-Cluster | ft name, dynamicquorum, witnessdynamicweight`

```
Name              DynamicQuorum WitnessDynamicWeight
----              ------------- --------------------
diskcluster          1                    0
```

Comment: What's the output of `Get-Cluster | ft name, dynamicquorum, witnessdynamicweight`? Sounds like Dynamic Quorum / Witness to me.

Comment: @lenniery I modified the question with the output.

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2016/03/21/behavior-of-dynamic-witness-on-windows-server-2012-r2-failover-clustering-3/) and search for _Dynamic Quorum / Witness_, this should answer your question. I've got no time to answer atm, sorry